# Unrecognised method call with NHibernate and Linq when only date part required

Tags: c#, linq, date, nhibernate

I have the following class defined

```
public class IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive
{
    public virtual String VisitNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual String WardCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String ClinicCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String DoctorCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String AppointmentStatusCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual String EpisodeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual String ConsultantCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String ReferrerCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String MainSpecialtyCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String MessageType { get; set; }
    public virtual String EpisodeStatusCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String ParentEpisodeType { get; set; }
    public virtual String AdmissionType { get; set; }
    public virtual String AdmitReason { get; set; }
    public virtual String BuildingCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String BedNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual String CategoryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String ConsultantName { get; set; }
    public virtual String DischargeDestination { get; set; }
    public virtual String DischargeMethod { get; set; }
    public virtual String FacilityCode { get; set; }
    public virtual String ReferralReason { get; set; }
    public virtual String ReferrerAssigningAuthority { get; set; }
    public virtual String ReferrerName { get; set; }
    public virtual String currentStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual String AppointmentTypeText { get; set; }
    public virtual String TCILocation { get; set; }

    public virtual Boolean analysed { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime AdmitDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StopDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ScheduledDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DischargeDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime timeOfInsert { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime timeOfAnalyse { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime TCIDate { get; set; }

    public virtual int TempAppointmentKey { get; set; }
```

I need to find any appointments a patient has on a given date, for this I need to extract just the date

```
            using (ISessionFactory factory = CreateSessionFactory())
            {
                using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
                {
                    var query = session.QueryOver<IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive>()
                        .Where(a => (a.PatientNumber == MRN) && (a.AppointmentDateTime.ToShortDateString() == DateOfAppointment.ToShortDateString()))
                        .List()
                        .ToList<IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive>();


                    if (query != null)
                    {
                        results = query;
                    }
                }
            }
```

However when this code executes I am getting an error

**Unrecognised method call in epression a.AppointmentDateTime.ToShortDateString()**

I presume that is because it is unable to determine the SQL for ToShortDateString - so how should I code this requirement. Database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for something like this (this is using the Linq provider and not QueryOver):

```
[Test]
public void CanQueryByDate()
{
    var x = (from o in db.Orders
        where o.OrderDate.Value.Date == new DateTime(1998, 02, 26)
        select o).ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(6, x.Count());
}
```

The unit tests are generally a good place to find basic examples.  See here for the nhibernate unit tests for linq that are specific to date time examples:

https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/Linq/DateTimeTests.cs

Comment: Thanks. I cheated eventually - it is not going to win any awards for efficiency but does work. I'll put the result in an answer rather than squeeze it in here.

Answer (score 0):

The query is split into two, with the date check done in the second half on the result of querying on the patient identifier. So the if statement at the end becomes;

```
if (query != null)
{
    results = (from a in query where a.AppointmentDateTime.Date == DateOfAppointment.Date select a).ToList<IRM_TEMP_Appointment_archive>();
}
```

Because the later query is not being converted into T-SQL then there is no concern on their being no equivalent of the Date function.